# Text letter by letter appears immediately with while loop

Tags: c#

I'm doing a text that appears letter by letter.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static int index = 0;
    public int times = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        times = 1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string texto = "Developed by HugoRod";
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (times==1)
        {
            label1.Text = texto.Substring(0, index) + "_";
            index++;
            if (index==texto.Length)
            {
                index = 0;
                times = 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I use

```
while (times == 1)
```

Instead of:

```
if (times == 1)
```

The text goes immediately, can someone tell me why?
Thanks,

Comment: Please learn to indent your code.. it'll become somewhat obvious why a while loop behaves in the way you describe.

Comment: @HugoRod - look up UI dispatching  - the reason the `if` approach works is that your timer method gets invoked anew each time and the UI refreshes - if you do the updates in a `while` loop there won't be any UI updates in between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `times = 2` only AFTER you've output all of the characters.  So if you run your code inside a `while` loop, it will continue to execute the loop over and over until `times` is no longer 1, which only occurs after all of the characters have been displayed.

Comment: except even if you fix this running this code in a `while` loop will still show all the text

Comment: Why downvote?  The answer is right and answers the specific question asked.  Just because there's an additional bug in the code does not affect my answer.

Comment: I think what OP didn't understand is that this while loop also blocks the ui thread. So the textbox is not redrawn until the method is finished (and the whole string is added).

Answer (score 1):

In your current code you are adding one character per tick of the timer.

When you change the content of a control on the screen the control invalidates part of the window to signal that it needs to be redrawn, it doesn't immediately redraw its section of the screen.  The window will receive a message in the same thread that your timer code is running on and, once the message pump gets to that message, will redraw whichever parts are marked as invalid.

The important part of that is that the screen updates are running on the same thread as your timer code.  While your timer code is running the screen will not update.  This is why when you have a very long-running piece of code that runs on the UI thread the UI will stop updating and won't react to anything until the long-running code exits and allows the message pump to process queued messages.  You can test this by inserting a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` to get a 1-second delay in your timer handler and see that the screen does not update during that time.

Now, if you were to put a `while` loop that sequentially places each of the characters into the textbox in a single 'long' (relatively) process, the message telling the form that it needs to repaint will not be processed between additions.  Once you exit your code the queued messages are processed and the screen is redrawn one time.  Don't worry about the mechanism behind that, just accept that you won't get multiple repaints from multiple updates.

Not only will the screen not being updated between additions, but the whole loop will finish in an incredibly short amount of time.  Ignoring the refresh rate of ~17ms - which is likely to be a lot longer than your loop takes to complete - your eyes can't detect things happening in millisecond time.